# catkin returns array of functions in opencv

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to do wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages

But I get this error:

> Linking CXX executable image_converter
> > CMakeFiles/image_converter.dir/src/image_converter.cpp.o:
> > In function `main': > image_converter.cpp:(.text+0x50): > undefined reference to >` ros::init(int&, char**,
> > std::basic_string<char,
> > std::char_traits,
> > std::allocator > const&,
> > unsigned int)'

and so on

**My CmakeLists.txt**

> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
> project(learning_image_transport)
>
> find_package(OpenCV)
> include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
> > 
> add_executable(image_converter
> > src/image_converter.cpp)   
> > target_link_libraries(image_converter
> > ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS   genmsg   cv_bridge

> image_transport   roscpp   std_msgs )

**And Package.xml**

> <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
> <buildtool_depend>genmsg</buildtool_depend>
> <build_depend>image_transport</build_depend>   <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
> <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
> <build_depend>cv_bridge</build_depend>
> <build_depend>opencv2</build_depend>
> <run_depend>opencv2</run_depend>
> <run_depend>cv_bridge</run_depend>
> <run_depend>image_transport</run_depend>
> <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
> <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/118361/catkin-returns-array-of-functions-in-opencv/) by [ProstoTsar](https://answers.ros.org/users/10881/prostotsar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Besides ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} you need to link your exec against ${catkin_LIBRARIES}:

```
target_link_libraries(image_converter ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )
```

Note that you need to call

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS genmsg cv_bridge image_transport roscpp std_msgs )
```

before target_link_libraries

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ProstoTsar](https://answers.ros.org/users/10881/prostotsar/) on 2014-01-16**:
I have already tried this but nothing changed

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-01-16**:
Looking at the order in your CMakeLists.txt: Could be that you have to call 'find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS genmsg cv_bridge image_transport roscpp std_msgs )' before add_executable and target_link_libraries  ....?

**Comment by [ProstoTsar](https://answers.ros.org/users/10881/prostotsar/) on 2014-01-16**:
No, my Cmakelists order is:
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
find_package(OpenCV)
...
add_executable...
target_link_libraries....
CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs cv_bridge image_geometry image_transport
DEPENDS system_lib opencv genmsg
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
...

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-01-16**:
Why don't you put find_package( catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ... to the top of your file, ( before target_link_libraries(image_converter ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ) ? The var ${catkin_LIBRARIES} depends on it, so I think find_package( catkin must be called first!?

**Comment by [ProstoTsar](https://answers.ros.org/users/10881/prostotsar/) on 2014-01-16**:
Thanks a lot, now it is everything OK